# insertBefore - swap two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

If you look at my website [link to website](http://heilpraktik.identitest.dk/), you will find an ID for the content (#content) and one for the sidebar (#sidebar).
(It's located in "#wrapper > #main > .avada-row > #content/#sidebar")

I have tried to switch order/place so #sidebar comes before #content. I tried with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
    $(function(){
        $('#sidebar').each(function () {
            $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev('#content'));
        });
    });//]]>  
</script>
```

Here is a JSFiddle example (it works in JSFiddle but not on my website):
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThrS9/)

I really hope someone can help me!

NOTE!:
This line of javascript works too in JSFiddle but not on my website:

```
$('#sidebar').insertBefore($('#content'));
```

I guess there is no need to use each function?

And sorry - I forgot to say that I know nothing about javascript programming. I just try my best with no luck I guess :/

Best Regards

**I can't comment my own question, so I will do it here:**

Karl-André - Yeah, I am aware of the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" but i don't know how to fix it.

Arjun - I tried that too but $ is being overriding and therefore is does not work :/

Zessx - Can you help me find out what is overriding $ ?

The code:

```
jQuery('#sidebar').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).insertBefore(jQuery(this).prev('#content'));
});
```

Did not work when I insert it in head.

Thank you so much! I really appreciate it !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Have you checked the console? You have an error : `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `.

Comment: Code seems to have multiple elements with ID sidebar _FYI:_ **IDs** must be unique!

Comment: Yes you dont need a `$.each()` method, because ids are unique per element.

Comment: `$` is undefined, but not `jQuery`, something is overriding `$`.

Comment: Your code is not recognizing the $ variable - when I use this in console it works:jQuery('#sidebar').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).insertBefore(jQuery(this).prev('#content'));
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is overriding the jQuery `$` :

```
> $
  undefined
> jQuery
  function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}
```

If you change your script by this one, you'll see it works :

```
jQuery('#sidebar').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).insertBefore(jQuery(this).prev('#content'));
});
```

Now, we need to define *what* is overriding `$`.

As a workaround, you still can use this code in your `<head>`, [as mentioned in jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (search for "Aliasing the jQuery namespace") :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#sidebar').each(function () {
        $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev('#content'));
    });
});
```

Comment: You can save yourself a little typing: `(function($){ $('#sidebar').insertBefore('#content'); })(jQuery);`

Comment: Okay now this script works:

`jQuery('#sidebar').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).insertBefore(jQuery(this).prev('#content'));
});`

But not in <head> .. only in <body>.
I want the site to load the script before the divs.

Can you help me find out what is overriding `$`? :/

Comment: @ShaneAkira I added a piece of code. With it, you'll be able to use `$` as an alias of jQuery without conflict.

Comment: And, you can't execute this piece of js before the DOM is loaded, because your **need** it. How can you swap two divs if they're still not created ?

Comment: Now it works in `<head>` with the last script you posted! Thank you so much Zessx!!!! And of course you cannot swap two divs before they're are created - I see.. How come you can't you use this line `$('#sidebar').insertBefore($('#content'));` after `jQuery(function($) {` ?? :)

Comment: `jQuery(function($) {});` wait for the DOM to be ready, and define `$` as a jQuery alias. That's why you're allowed to use `$('#sidebar').insertBefore($('#content'));` **inside** this function.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to add the content above the selected **div** just use
$('#sidebar').insertBefore('#content');

-Thanks.